# Не могу понять как правильно в angularJS добавить объекты к массиву?

Tags: json, angularjs

Не могу понять как правильно добавить объекты к массиву. Т.е нужно добавить отдельно категорию и возможность добавлять параметры категории. Т.к.  не совсем понимаю принцип работы многомерных массивов. Прошу помощи у знатоков, для решения данной проблемы. Ниже пример на планкере.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="DataBaseController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="addNameCat" placeholder="Название новой категории">
  <button ng-click="addCatItem()" type="submit">+ Категорию</button>
  <div ng-repeat="cat in database">
    <p>{{cat.category}}
      <button ng-click="removeCatItem($index)">x</button>
      <input type="text" ng-model="addNameParam" placeholder="Новый параметр"> 
      <button ng-click="addCatItem()" type="submit">+ Параметр</button>
    </p>
    <ul ng-repeat="datafields in cat.datafields">
      <li>{{datafields.param}}
        <button ng-click="removeParamItem($parent.$index, $index)">x</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

**JSON**

```
[{
  "category": "Категория 1",
  "datafields": [{
    "param": "Категория1 - Текст1"
  }]
}, {
  "category": "Категория 2",
  "datafields": [{
    "param": "Категория2 - Текст1"
  }, {
    "param": "Категория2 - Текст2"
  }]
}]
```

**JS**

```
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('DataBaseController', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get('data.json').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.database = data;
        $scope.addNameCat = '';
        $scope.addNameParam = '';
        $scope.addCatItem = function() {
          if ($scope.addNameCat !== '') {

            // ??? Добавляем категорию

            $scope.addNameCat = '';
          }
        };
        $scope.addParamItem = function() {
          if ($scope.addNameParam !== '') {

            // ??? Добавляем параметр категории

            $scope.addNameParam = '';
          }
        }
        $scope.removeCatItem = function(indexCat) {
          data.splice(indexCat, 1);
        };
        $scope.removeParamItem = function(indexCat, indexParam) {
          data[indexCat].datafields.splice(indexParam, 1);
        };
      });
    });
```

Пример на **[planker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CEsxY3ToXE1sFqNZieBT?p=preview)**

Comment: Многомерных массивов здесь не видно. Объекты в массив добавляются как обычно в js (с помощью push). Вот переработанный пример ваш: https://plnkr.co/edit/ayCntw

Comment: все намного проще чем я думал, спасибо за помощь!